# HTML in Laravel translated string

Tags: laravel

I am translating the following string:

```
<p> {{{ trans('myapp.signup_instructions', [ 'email' => '<strong>'.$invitation->email .'</strong>']) }}}</p>
```

However on our website we can still see the "`<strong>user@domain.com</strong>`" as text. We were aiming to convert the just the e-mail parameter in the string into **bold text**

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It looks weird, it should be work.... Can you try this `<p> {{{ "<strong>{trans('myapp.signup_instructions', [ 'email' => $invitation->email ])}</strong>" }}}</p>`

Comment: wouldn't that make the entire paragraph bold? I just need the e-mail to be bold.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I got your question now. Ya, my method is a not good idea

Comment: If you're on Laravel 5 you need to use `{!! .. !!}` instead of `{{{ .. }}}`

Comment: So {!! ... !!} is there for Angular co-existence or does it have a special meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you should use `{!! !!}` to output variable without escaping:

```blade
{!! trans('myapp.signup_instructions', ['email' => '<strong>'.$invitation->email .'</strong>']) !!}
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 (Blade Tag Changes section)

PS. This does not related to AngularJS